# How can i read sensors from Rasbpery pi?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I want to make a generic class which can read all values of wholes type sensors. my question is how I can read sensor data? 
are there files in which backup data if so what is the location?.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for http://pi4j.com/

You can build your lib on top of it. It is capable for all types of low-level communication over the GPIOs and also supports I²C or SPI.

There are no general backup files or anything else you can use but only record live data.

Comment: i found it but for example i want read temperature value which method i can use ? thanks

Comment: This is not as simple as you think it is. The lib just provides access to the "pins". You need to read the specifications for the sensor. For example: how to ask for data? and how to interpret the data? In the end it will result in sending and receiving a bunch of bytes over the wire(s).

Comment: ah ok , do you have any example please ?

Comment: the sensors save data in files ?

Comment: The sensors (it does not matter which one) just reads and sends data from / to a pin. Without any application / driver there is no save data. I don't have any simple sample code available. Here is an sample for an i²c sensor from the pi4j project: https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/blob/41b2b965f2d82b7329af691eecc5f5a568292829/pi4j-device/src/main/java/com/pi4j/component/temperature/impl/Tmp102.java